# How can I perform bulk insert into MariaDB using JdbcTemplate in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb, jdbctemplate

I want to perform bulk insert into MariaDB using JdbcTemplate in Spring, but even when I append
?rewriteBatchedStatements=true to the jdbc-url, the inserts are still being done one by one.

my code works like this

INSERT INTO tbl (1, 2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
INSERT INTO tbl (1, 2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
INSERT INTO tbl (1, 2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)

i wanna this
INSERT INTO tbl (1, 2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...), (val1, val2, ...), ...

Is there any other way? What am I missing?

This is my code down here

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:log4jdbc:mariadb://ip/db?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&profileSQL=true&logger=Slf4JLogger&maxQuerySizeToLog=999999



public void insertBatch(List<object> objectList) {
        
        String sql = "";
        sql +=  "INSERT INTO TBL_NAME" +
                " (columns1, 2...) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?...) ";
        
        jdbcDBTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                object object = objectList.get(i);
                ps.setInt(1, object.getCol1());
                ps.setInt(2, object.getCol2());
            }
            
            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return tblInfoDetailList.size();
            }
        });
```

it's toooo slow.. plz help me

Comment: I got it!!!!! It's because there's log4jdbc in the jdbc-url!!!!!!!